# equalHeights Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребят, есть вот такой плагин, может кто подскажет, как сделать проверку, чтобы при ресайзе окна, когда разрешение будет меньше 767px, он отключался ? буду очень признателен

```
(function($) {

$.fn.equalHeights = function() {
    var maxHeight = 0,
        $this = $(this);

    $this.each( function() {
        var height = $(this).innerHeight();

        if ( height > maxHeight ) { maxHeight = height; }
    });

    return $this.css('height', maxHeight);
};

// auto-initialize plugin
$('[data-equal]').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        target = $this.data('equal');
    $this.find(target).equalHeights();
});

 })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно подписаться на событие `resize` и сбрасывать установленную высоту если ширина окна меньше необходимой.

```js
    (function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    var equalizer = function (elements, options) {
        elements.height('auto');
        if (typeof options.breakPoint === 'number' && (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth) <= options.breakPoint) {
            return;
        }
        var maxHeight = 0;
        elements.each(function () {
            var height = $(this).innerHeight();

            if (height > maxHeight) { maxHeight = height; }
        });
        return elements.height(maxHeight);
    }

    $.fn.equalHeights = function (options) {
        var elements = $(this);

        $(window).on('resize', function () {
            equalizer(elements, options);
        });

        return equalizer(elements, options);
    };

    // auto-initialize plugin
    $('[data-equal]').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var target = $this.data('equal');
        var breakPoint = $this.data('equal-breakpoint')
        $this.find(target).equalHeights({
            breakPoint: breakPoint
        });
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

```css
.inner {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-equal=".inner" data-equal-breakpoint="767">
  <div class="inner">123</div>
  <div class="inner">345<br>567</div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, это то, что нужно. Но там еще небольшая загвоздка, скрипт инлайново в стили элементу добавляет фикс высоту, не могу понять, как ее убирать когда скрипт отключается ?

Comment: `elements.height('auto');`
вот эта строчка сбрасывает высоту

Comment: Спасибо, очень выручили

Comment: Я прошу прощение, но скрипт не работает, он просто задает элементам height: auto, на всех разрешениях. Возможно вы завтра сможете посмотреть, что там не так ? Уже так намучался с ним (